# Prisma: Create timestamp field without date

Tags: node.js, postgresql, timestamp, backend, prisma

I want to create a field in my table in a timestamp type but without a date stamp. The DateTime type generates that WITH a date stamp but i dont want that. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a time field [time(stamp) types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/curren/datatype-datetime.html):

```
select '2020-09-28 12:22'::timestamp::time;
time   
----------
 12:22:00

\d ts_test 
                         Table "public.ts_test"
  Column  |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 ts_tz    | timestamp with time zone    |           |          | 
 ts       | timestamp without time zone |           |          | 
 ts_txt   | character varying           |           |          | 
 time_fld | time without time zone      |           |          | 

insert into  ts_test (time_fld) values ('2020-09-28 12:22');

select * from ts_test where time_fld is not null;
 ts_tz |  ts  | ts_txt | time_fld 
-------+------+--------+----------
 NULL  | NULL | NULL   | 12:22:00
```

The timestamp will be truncated to a time.

Comment: thanks for your answer @Adrian Klaver but i want to do that with prisma. Is that not possible? :)

Comment: I don't know Prisma. I do see that it maps `Datetime` to `timestamp`. Then it should work if you send the `Datetime` to the database table field  of type `time` as Postgres would cast the `timestamp` to the `time` type and truncate it to a time as above. I would think a simple test table could confirm that.